# What can I use to slow down a Flash .swf file's playback speed?

Tags: windows-xp, flash, speed, flash-player, playback

I've got a pile of .swf files here that are static animations, and I'd like to find some way of playing them at half or quarter speed. Preferably one that doesn't rely on exploiting sloppy browser/antivirus software processor usage.

Is there some sort of Windows-compatible Flash player with this functionality? Preferably open source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to use CheatEngine. Download & Run it, and choose the process (your web browser) which you want to "slow down". Then check the box that says SpeedHack, and enter the decimal multiplier of the speed you want the application to run at. For example, 0.5 would half the speed, 2 would double it.

Then, click apply. I'm not sure how it would handle audio.... but I don't think that you need that (?)

Comment: was thinking the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Enounce](http://www.enounce.com) for flash files. You can speed up and slow down the playing speed. They have a free 7 day trial and the price is under $30:

> Online video is everywhere – lectures, labs, tutorials, certification
>   courses, seminars, news, sports and, of course, YouTube! MySpeed from
>   Enounce lets you change the playback speed of Flash video without any
>   loss of audio quality. (No chipmunk sound.) It’s like speed-reading
>   for video! If your Windows PC or Mac can view videos on YouTube,
>   MySpeed will work!